# File created in jboss/bin instead of jboss/standalone/deployments

Tags: java, jboss

I wrote the following code to write a file on my jBoss server:

```
Path path = Paths.get("myfile.csv");
BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
writer.write(csvtext, 0, csvtext.length());
writer.close();
```

The file is saved in jboss/bin

Now I want to add a link in my front end to be able to download the csv. But I don't know what URL to use because the file csv is store in jboss/bin.

How can I do? Should I store it in jboss/standalone/deployments? How?

Comment: Have you considered how this will work if your application must run on multiple nodes in a cluster? Do you have an Apache httpd (or similar) instance sitting in front of your JBoss instance(s)?

Comment: I just have Jboss 7.1. No clusters, no httd or similar... nothing else to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html  - it takes any string, or uri.  I think with JBoss 7, you'll only be able to serve files by servlet, so maybe start with this, and modify to CSV instead of images?   http://balusc.blogspot.com.es/2007/04/imageservlet.html